# Minimization and Manipulate[Plot] not working as expected

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

Quite new to Mathematica, and I have been trying to fix the code using online resources for the past few days now. I am trying to plot and minimise this equation to learn more about its properties:

(1) $t=a+b$
(2) $p=u+(1-u)(1-e^{-\lambda b})$
(3) $u = \frac{(1-e^{-\lambda a})\sigma}{(1-e^{-\lambda a})\sigma + (e^{-\lambda a})(1-\sigma)}$

$\sigma, \lambda \text{ and } p$ are constant terms and $b$ is determined uniquely by choice variable $a$ in equation (2)/(3). There are two other variables, $t$ and $a$ - I would like to explore the relationship between these.

I have tried to Plot this relationship for varying and specified levels of $\sigma, \lambda \text{ and } p$, but I get empty axes each time. This is what I have used.

```
t = a + b
p = u + (1 - u) (1 - E^{-λ b})
u = ((1 - 
E^{-λ a}) (σ))/((1 - 
 E^{-λ a}) (σ) + (E^{-λ a}) (1 - σ))
Manipulate[Plot[t, {a, 0, 1}], {λ, 0, 1}, {σ, 0.5, 1}, {p, 0, 1}]
```

Being unable to find a plot, I have also tried to minimize $t$ with respect to $k$, with $\sigma, \lambda \text{ and } p$ as constants. Essentially the minimisation problem is:

$\underset{k}\min t$ subject to $p=u+(1-u)(1-e^{-\lambda b})$  where $u = \frac{(1-e^{-\lambda a})\sigma}{(1-e^{-\lambda a})\sigma + (e^{-\lambda a})(1-\sigma)}$

I have tried different variations of this:

```
Assuming[a > 0 && t > 0 && b > 0 && λ > 0 && 0 < p < 1 && 0.5 < σ < 1, Minimize[{t, p == u + (1 - u) (1 - E^(-λ b))}, a]]
```

And I have also tried substituting the value of $u$ as per equation (3). However I am unable to output any meaningful results.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can reformulate the plot or minimisation expressions so I can output meaningful results?

Thank you

Comment: First suggestions: use `==` (not `=`) in equations inside `Minimize` and simple `()` (not `{}`) for the exponents.

Comment: Thank you – b.gatessucks
I have included those suggestions and now I am getting an indeterminate result - definitely not something that I expected. This is what I used now:
    `Assuming[a > 0 && t > 0 && b > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 && 0 < p < 1 && 
  0.5 < \[Sigma] < 1, 
 Minimize[{t, p == u + (1 - u) (1 - E^(-\[Lambda] b))}, a]]`

And this is the output
    `{-\[Infinity], {a -> Indeterminate}}`

Comment: You can try to solve (2) for `u`, substitute into (3) and solve for `b`; this way you will have an explicit expression to `NMinimize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it for b, for given value of p.

```
       a = .1; σ = .2; λ = .2;
       p == (1 - Exp[-λ a]*σ)/(1 - 
       Exp[-λ a]*σ + 
       Exp[-λ a] (1 - σ)) + (1 - (1 - 
       Exp[-λ a]*σ)/(1 - Exp[-λ a]*σ + 
       Exp[-λ a] (1 - σ))) (1 - Exp[-λ *b])

      Solve[p == 0.506234 + 0.493766 (1 - E^(-0.2 b)), b]
      (*out put*)
      (*{{b -> -5. Log[-2.02525 (-1. + p)]}}*)
      or
      (*{{b -> -5. Log[-2.02525 (-1. + p)]}} /. Rule -> Equal*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to keep $p$ a constant - perhaps it would be better the express that equation in terms of $a$?
If I combine (2) and (3), then I get
$p=\frac{(1-e^{-\lambda a})\sigma}{(1-e^{-\lambda a})\sigma + (e^{-\lambda a})(1-\sigma)}+(1-\frac{(1-e^{-\lambda a})\sigma}{(1-e^{-\lambda a})\sigma + (e^{-\lambda a})(1-\sigma)})(1-e^{-\lambda b})$

This leaves one degree of freedom, so when $a$ is chosen, $b$ should be pinned down. I have tried (unsuccessfully) to get Mathematica to form an expression for the above with a as the subject for my constraint

Comment: I have updated the answes. Is it helpful?